# array of maps help c++ / qt

Tags: c++, qt4

I don't know if I'm doing this right, c++ is not a native language for me.

```
QMap < QString, QString > *mapArray;
QMap < QString, QString > map[10];
mapArray = map;

mapArray[0].insert("key1", "value1");
mapArray[0].insert("key1-1", "value1-1");
mapArray[1].insert("key2", "value2");
mapArray[2].insert("key3", "value3");
mapArray[2].insert("key3-1", "value3-1"); ...
```

Now I want to iterate through the entire mapArray.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: While you are iterating the array do you need both the key and value, or just the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You seem to be making things much more complicated than necessary. At least from the looks of things, you don't need a pointer or an array, just a QMap object:

```
QMap<QString, QString> map;

map.insert("Key1", "value1");
map.insert("Key1-1", "value1-1");
map.insert("key2", "value2");

QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator pos;

for (pos=map.constBegin(); pos!=map.constEnd(); ++pos)
    std::cout << pos.key() << ": " << pos.value() << "\n";
```

Comment: I'm actually using the array of maps because there are submenus linked to to each mapArray[X].

Comment: @uer375566: It's still not (at all) clear to me that you need an array of maps. Since you've (at least in the example) kept your keys unique overall, you can/could apparently use a single map for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the pointer. Get rid of it and just use `map` in its place:

```
QMap < QString, QString > map[10];

map[0].insert("key1", "value1");
map[0].insert("key1-1", "value1-1");
map[1].insert("key2", "value2");
map[2].insert("key3", "value3");
map[2].insert("key3-1", "value3-1"); ...
```

To iterate through them all, you'll need to iterate through the array, then through the maps.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for (QMap<QString, QString>::iterator it = map[i].begin(); it != map[i].end(); ++it)
    {
         const QString& key = it->first;
         QString& value = it->second;
         ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `QMap` iterator is a `QPair` of the key and value. You can retrieve them separately using `first` and `seconds` as I have above.